# NSPredicate fetching objects with changing IN clause

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

So I have a relationship setup set up like this :

1. User -> (many)Post *posts*
2. User(many) <-> (many)User *friends*

A User has many Posts and a User has many Friends(Users). I'd like to be able to get all of the posts that a users set of friends has created. Easy enough.

Heres the tricky bit. I'd like the FetchedResultsController to update the list of posts when a friend is added or removed from the friends list without rebuilding the Fetched Results Controller. I would also like the fetched entities to return Post objects so I don't have to do any extra work to the Fetched Results Controllers fetchedObjects array.

Is this possible? Here's my current FRC Setup

```
NSFetchRequest *postRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Post"];
postRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user IN %@",[self.user  friends]];

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:postRequest managedObjectContext:....];
```

Comment: I think the straight answer is no, that's not possible.  But hopefully you will get some good work-arounds.  For which purpose, can you clarify: a) do you need the FRC's section-building capabilities (i.e. sectionNameKeyPath), and b) do you need the FRC's change-tracking capabilities (ie. the delegate methods)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The FRC will not observe this for you directly as it is only observing changes to `Post` objects. You will need to observe changes to the `friends` set yourself and then update the fetch request (because there is no link back to the mutated set of friends) and call `performFetch:` on the FRC explicitly.